# Angular 8 and async @Input

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-observable

In the first component, I have a variable `x` that is a result of a subscription to an observable(s). Since getting this variable's value involves a lot of `swithcMap`-ing and similar stuff, I don't want to repeat all the convoluted logic in the second component, where I need the variable `x` as well (and not only in html template). Is `@Input` right for this or are there any other means to achieve it?

Comment: well, without knowing what you are doing, I believe this would be a good usage of Input. You have a "smart" component doing all the "calculation" to find the value, and just passing the result as input to the child "display" component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article that suggests four alternatives, any one of which might be applicable to your use case:

> **[Sharing Data Between Angular Components - Four Methods](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)**
>
> *Apr 30, 2017 written by Jeff Delaney*
>
> - Parent to Child: Sharing Data via Input
> - Child to Parent: Sharing Data via ViewChild
> - Child to Parent: Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter
> - Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service

You haven't given enough details to be sure which - if any - of these methods might satisfy your use case.  For example, *IS* there a parent/child relationship between your two components?

Here's another example, which illustrates the "Child-to-Parent, Output/EventEmitter" scenario above:

[Angular 7-Sharing variable between components dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168574/angular-7-sharing-variable-between-components-dynamically)